# The specific case won't pass elif on line 8:

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, logical-operators

I'm solving puzzles on Dcoder, I decided to hard code the solution and it still didn't pass all the tests.

I expanded the code to what it is now (the code that I pasted) to include all of the cases I could think of. I found a specific case that it should pass, but for some reason that doesn't happen.

I also tried adding brackets in if/elif block, but that didn't change anything (I didn't expect it to, but I still tried)

```py
def damn(a, b, c, d, n, m):
    if a+c <= n:
        if b <= m and d <= m:
            return True
    elif a+d <= n:
        if b <= m and c <= m:
            return True
    elif a+c <= m:
        if b <= n and d <= n:
            return True
    elif a+d <= m:
        if b <= n and c <= n:
            return True
    elif b+c <= n:
        if a <= m and d <= m:
            return True
    elif b+d <= n:
        if a <= m and c <= m:
            return True
    elif b+c <= m:
        if a <= n and d <= n:
            return True
    elif b+d <= m:
        if a <= n and c <= n:
            return True
    else:
        return False

if damn(2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 3):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

```py
elif a+c <= m:
        if b <= n and d <= n:
            return True
```

That should be:

3 <= 3

2 <= 4 and 4 <= 4

output of all is true, those are the values that come up when I print them before if/elif/else block, yet for some reason function "damn" returns false.

Does anyone have an idea why does that happen and can you explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first if statement is passing:

```
if a + c <= n:
```

So the code never reaches the elif branch you want it to:

```
a, b, c, d, n, m  
2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 3
```

> 2 + 1 ( 3 )  <= 4

You probably want to be combining the if statements and not nesting them:

```
if a + c <= n and b <= m and d <= m:
```

Comment: Combining if statements should be better for computer memory, correct?

Comment: In this scenario you don't really have a choice, so you will need to combine the statements. I don't think it will save memory, as the variables are already declared and initialized as parameters, so all of the values are already created in memory -- it may save a very very very small amount of time doing the comparisons

Comment: I didn't phrase that correctly, I apologize. I meant if I don't combine them, but switch elifs to ifs instead it works the same as when I combine the statements. So my question is combining better in this case? I don't think it really matters because once it returns it won't check the other statements anyway, but I'm unsure.

Comment: You can use multiple `if` statements and leave the code as it is or else use `elif`and combine the statements - the difference is that if the code enters one of the `elif` statements then it wont attempt to enter any others